# How to add $watch to track a value in $cookies inside Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angularjs-directive, watch

I'm having difficulty getting a directive to update dynamically when a value in $cookies changes. Basically, it is a login/logout system where a custom directive should be displayed or hidden depending on whether the user is logged in or not. Below is the code I have so far. I know my directive is very scrappy and probably bloated but I am trying to get the functionality in place before cleaning it up.

At the moment the `adminLogin` directive doesn't display after login unless the entire page is manually refreshed. Also, the directive doesn't go away after log out unless I add `$scope.loggedInUser = false;` to the `logout()` function, which is not what I want. My question is what is the recommended way to use a `$watch` inside a directive so that it shows/hides based on the `$cookies.loggedInUser` value?

I've already tried adding `$cookies.loggedInUser` as the first param to the `$watch`function, my logic being any change to its value would trigger the code inside the function but that doesn't seem to work inside the directive and I'm not sure why.

I've spent a couple of days on it now and I think I've tried every angle offered from other SO questions as well as Googling and reading docs. But so far nothing has worked so any guidance is much appreciated!

**LOGIN CTRL**

```
.controller('AdminLoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$cookies', 'AuthService', 'flashMessageService', '$log',
        function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $cookies, AuthService, flashMessageService, $log) {
          // $scope.adminLoggedIn = false;

          $scope.credentials = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
          };

          $scope.login = function(credentials) {
            console.log('in login....');
            AuthService.login(credentials).then(
              function(res) {

               // THIS SHOULD BE WATCHED INSIDE DIRECTIVE TO SHOW/HIDE TEMPLATE
                $cookies.put('loggedInUser', res.data);

                // USER SAVED TO COOKIES FINE HERE
                console.log('User from Cookies...', $cookies.get("loggedInUser"));

                $location.path('/admin/pages');
              },
              function(err) {
                flashMessageService.setMessage(err.data);
                $log.log(err);
              });
            };
        }
    ])
```

**LOGGED IN DIRECTIVE**

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', ["ngCookies"])
  .directive('adminLogin', ['$rootScope','$cookies','AuthService','flashMessageService','$location',
    function($rootScope,$cookies,AuthService,flashMessageService,$location) {
      return {
        controller: function($scope, $cookies,$rootScope) {

// CONSOLE LOG IN DIRECTIVE CONFIRMS LOGGED IN USER IS SAVED IN COOKIES
          console.log("Func called in DIRECTIVE ", $cookies.get("loggedInUser"));
          $scope.loggedInUser = $cookies.get("loggedInUser");

          /* NEED HELP WITH WATCH IMPLEMENTATION */
          $scope.$watch(/* what to watch */, function(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log('WATCH ', nVal, oVal);
            /* ??? */
          })

          console.log('logInUser In Dir ', $scope.loggedInUser);

          $scope.logout = function() {
            console.log('Logout in Directive...');
            AuthService.logout().then(
              function() {
                $cookies.remove('loggedInUser'); // Want this to be watched
                $scope.loggedInUser = false; // Works but not ideal!
                $location.path('/admin/login');
                flashMessageService.setMessage("Successfully logged out");

              }, function(err) {
                  console.log('there was an error tying to logout', err);
              });
          };

        },
        templateUrl: 'partials/directives/admin-login.html'
      };
    }
  ])
```

**DIRECTIVE TEMPLATE**

```
<div ng-if='loggedInUser'>
    Welcome {{loggedInUser}} |  <a href="admin/pages">My Admin</a> | <a href ng-click='logout()'>Logout</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function in the template to check the cookie:

```
<div ng-show="loggedInUser=getUserCookie()">
    Welcome {{loggedInUser}} |  <a href="admin/pages">My Admin</a> | <a href ng-click='logout()'>Logout</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.getUserCookie = function() {
    var loggedInUser = $cookies.get('loggedInUser');
    return loggedInUser;
};
```

On each digest cycle, the function retrieves the latest value of the cookie.

Comment: Fantastic!This perfectly and elegantly solves the problem.Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't watch `$cookies`.

If you want to notify your directive that something happened, you could just broadcast something on the root scope and listen for that in your directive, or store data in your AuthService when the user logs in and watch that instead.